# How to calculate a parameter between multiple models? asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I have multiple models and I am trying to calculate a parameter named total. I am new to MVC and are not really sure how to do this or where (seen that it should not be done in view that's for sure).

I have this parameter I have to calculate:

```
public class Bill
{
public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

by using these parameters:

```
public class Article
{
   public int Price { get; set; }
   public float Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and also:

```
public class BillLine
{
   public int DiscountValue { get; set; }
}
```

The total is calculated using those 3 values but I am not really sure how to do it. The program works like this: each billLine can have 1 article and 1 bill can have many bill lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per understanding I have following Code: Considering   `Quantity` refers to   no of Items it should be Int and Price Be a Float property. `TotalArticlePrice` is a calculated property.

```
public class Article
{
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }


    public float TotalArticlePrice
    {
        get
        {
            return Price * Quantity;
        }

    }
}
```

As you mentioned that  one BillLine has one Article so model should be as below with `Article`  property and `FinalBillLinePrice` which is calculated deducting the discout value

```
public class BillLine
{
    public int DiscountValue { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public float FinalBillLinePrice
    {
        get
        {
            return Article.TotalArticlePrice - DiscountValue;
        }

    }
}
```

finally,
As you mentioned One `Bill` May have Multiple `BillLine`,therefore Model should look like below, where `Total` property stores the Total Bill Price.

```
public class Bill
{
    public float Total
    {
        get
        {

            return BillLineList.Sum(x => x.FinalBillLinePrice);

        }

    }
    public List<BillLine> BillLineList { get; set; }
}
```

In case, I have misunderstood anything Please brief in comments.

Comment: your solution seems like the best one! the only problem i am facing now is the old database not wanting to update and even if i delete it and create a new one did not update

Comment: @RedDevil :Thanks. if it solves the problem please mark it as answer..Are you using any ORM (Entity Frmework)  and facing the issue updating the database.If so you may raise a seperate question with details & error. :)

Comment: I managed to update it but now it does not want to get the initializer data for the files i am doing these calculations meaning article,bill line and bill.

Comment: Managed to do it again but it still shows me the old Total values that i had hardcoded before in the initializer... i deleted the database and recreated it...updated it and it still shows me those values that are not even there anymore...

Comment: Ths looks to be the Mapping (EF) issue. Hard to analyse where actual trouble is...can you please post a detailed query with the code for mapping & initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a ViewModel by combining all the three classes and it will be easy for you to do all the calculation using this.

To get started in Using  ViewModel, please refer the links below.

[Understanding ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/QHQT270712-Understanding-ViewModel-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html)

[Multiple Models in a View in ASP.NET MVC 4 / MVC 5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your view models should look something like this:

```
public class BillLine
{
   public int DiscountValue { get; set; }
   public Article Article {get; set; }
}

public class Bill
{
    public List<BillLine> Lines { get; set;}
    public int Total { get 
    {
       int result;
       foreach var line in Lines {
           //Update result with your calculations 
       }
       return result;
    }
   }
}
```